# MongoClient.Schema is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I have created a model named session.js. I am working with MEAN stack application using Angular 4 and I'm stuck with the error below.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var schema = new MongoClient.Schema({

        name : String,
        description : String,
        fromDate : Date,
        toDate : Date
})

var Session = MongoClient.model('session',schema);

module.exports = Session;
```

Code gives me below error:

```
var schema = new MongoClient.Schema({

              ^
TypeError: MongoClient.Schema is not a constructor
```

Can anyone suggest me how to create above schema using MongoClient?

Comment: `Schema` is part of `mongoose` not `MongoClient`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [collections](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/tutorials/collections/) :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/YOUR_DB";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  const data = { name: "Company Inc", description: "..." };

  db.collection("datas").insertOne(data, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document inserted");
    db.close();
  });
});
```

If you want to create schema you can use ODM like [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
  name : String,
  description : String,
  fromDate : Date,
  toDate : Date
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a correct error because you are trying to use a function that doesn't exist!.

You are using `mongodb` npm and `MongoClient` doesnt have a `.Schema`

Maybe you are confussing [MongoDB](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/index.html) driver with [Mongoose ODM](http://mongoosejs.com)